# Using a randomly shuffled batch as input to a CNN from a tensor of image data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a network using STL-10 dataset.

I have extracted the data from the STL-10 binary files and converted them into numpy arrays. Then i have converted them to tensors using `tf.convert_to_tensor` function

Now I have a tensor of shape (5000,96,96,3)

I want to get a batch of size 32 from this tensor containing data for 5000 images, and the batches will be randomly shuffled in each iteration.

using `tf.train.batch` gives an error

```
`TypeError: `Tensor` objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`
```

How to do i get a batch of image data of size 32, which will be randomly shuffled in each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of `tf.train.batch`:

> The argument tensors can be a list or a dictionary of tensors. The
>   value returned by the function will be of the same type as tensors.

You need to convert your data into a list of 5000 tensors, each of them shaped (96,96,3).

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy arrays directly in tensorflow functions because tensorflow knows how to convert them.

```
# Form shuffled batch of data
def get_batch(inputs, targets, size):          
    '''
    Return a total of `size` random inputs and targets(or labels). 
    '''
    targets_shape = targets.shape
    num_data = targets_shape[0]
    # this is a list of the right number of indices in the indices range
    shuffled_indices = np.random.randint(0,num_data,size)
    #this takes the selected random elements
    inputs_shuffled = inputs[shuffled_indices,:,:,:]
    #depending on the target shape it could be  targets[idx,:,:,...]
    #this takes the corresponding targets
    targets_shuffle = targets[shuffled_indices,:]
    #return the shuffled data and targets
    return inputs_shuffled, targets_shuffle
```

Then you may use it in the trainning:

```
#This calls the function we created    
inputs_batch, targets_batch = get_batch(inputs_all,targets_all,batch_size)
#This tells to tensorflow which input goes to which placeholder
feed_dict={inputs_placeholder: inputs_batch, 
           targets_placeholder: targets_batch}
#This runs one step of the training
sess.run(train_step,feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

Hope I could help...

Answer (score 1):

Please check the usage of the `tf.train.batch`:

```
label_batch = tf.train.batch([label], capacity=20, batch_size=10, num_threads=2)
```

The disappearance of the brackets of `label` will cause such an error.